# How to Display Images Quickly from url in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5

My project is based on rating pictures. I want to know the best way to display images quickly in imageview from the link without memory leakage and without any crash. Since, in the future the images can be in the order of hundreds of thousands and I will have to display these images.
Is it necessary to download the picture first??? If anyone has knowledge about it then please provide me some solutions.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Use Lazy Loading of images as it will work like when image is available it will be displayed either wise not.

Comment: How would you display a picture from the internet without downloading???

Comment: ok it means it is important to downloading the images.

Comment: as long, as the beaming hasnt been invented, you will have to download it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the pictures asynchronously from the internet, which keeps the App responsive. There is already a solution for that, for example by calling the method

> [yourAsynchronousImageView
>   loadImageFromURLString:@"http://your.url/image.jpg"];

in

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AsynchronousImageView : UIImageView {
    NSURLConnection *connection;    
    NSMutableData *data;
    bool loading;
}  

@property bool loading;

- (void)loadImageFromURLString:(NSString *)theUrlString;

@end
```

and

```
#import "AsynchronousImageView.h"

@implementation AsynchronousImageView
@synthesize loading;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadImageFromURLString:(NSString *)theUrlString{ 
    self.image = nil;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                             [NSURL URLWithString:theUrlString]
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                         timeoutInterval:30.0];                          
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                  initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    loading=true;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData {    if (data == nil)
        data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048];                 

    [data appendData:incrementalData];}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection {    
    self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    data = nil; 
    connection = nil;
    loading=false;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```